# Lazy loading of list thumbnail in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to create a dynamic list with 1000 items with image inside it.The image has source from    the internet like

```
<img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png">
```

I am using jquery.I wanted the list with alt icon for the image till each image is loading and also the images should load one by one. But instead till all image loads, only empty screen is being showed.I have html code
and js code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>hi</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">

            <ul id="listId" data-role="listview">
                <li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png" width="640" height="640"></li>
                <li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png"></li>
                <li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png"></li>
                <li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png"></li>
                <li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png"></li>
            </ul>

            <script src="js/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function wlCommonInit(){


    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
        var temp='<li><img class="lazy" src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png"></li>';
        $("#listId").append(temp);
        $("#listId").listview("refresh");
        }
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
        effect: "fadeIn" 
    }).removeClass("lazy");
}
```

Please help to find the solution for me by giving ideas, documents or the solution itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

images will start loading before javascript even kicks in. if you are ok with forcing your clients needing js you can achieve it by using something like

```
<img src="path/to/generic/image.png" data-src="http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/images/zoom_image_search_screenshot.png" class="lazy">
```

then

```
$(".lazy").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.load($this.attr("data-src"),function(){
        $this.attr("src",$this.attr("data-src"));
    })
});
```

this is untested and you should use `prop` instead. this is what i would do in anycase. lost all hope in those lazyload plugins a while ago already

the other thing you could do is to add the generic image as a background to a div (if you know the sizes of your images) most browsers while an image is loading its transparent. that way you dont have to mess with js etc